# returned pointer address getting modified when ASLR turned on

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, aslr, char-pointer

I have this piece of C code running on development box with ASLR enabled. It is returning a char pointer (char *) to a function, but somehow few bytes in the returned pointer address are getting changed, printf output below:

```
kerb_selftkt_cache is 0x00007f0b8e7fc120
cache_str from get_self_ticket_cache 0xffffffff8e7fc120
```

The char pointer `0x00007f0b8e7fc120` is being returned to another function, which is getting modified as `0xffffffff8e7fc120` that differs from the original pointer address by one word (4-bytes) `0xffffffff` instead of `0x00007f0b`, the last four bytes (`8e7fc120`) being same. Any idea what might be going on? and how do I possibly fix this. The code is running on linux 64-bit architecture on Intel Xeon. This code is from an existing proprietary library, so I can't share the exact code, but the code logic looks something like this:

```
typedef struct mystr {
 int num;
 char addr[10];
}mystr;

static mystr m1;

char *get_addr() {
 return m1.addr;
}

void myprint() {
 printf("mystr m1 address %p\n",&m1);
 printf("mystr m1 addr %p\n",m1.addr);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

char *retadd;
myprint();

retadd = get_addr();
printf("ret address %p\n",retadd);

return 0;
}
```

retadd and m1.addr are different when ASLR is turned on.

Comment: What hardware/OS are you running this on? What library/framework is this code belong to? Or is this your own code? If so, can you share a minimum program that one can compile and run to reproduce the issue?...

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of your code. Looks like you have masking and sign extension happening.

Comment: It's almost certainly not got anything to do with ASLR. More likely a bug in your code. But no one can tell unless you show the code.

Comment: I've added sample code corresponding to what the original library code is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the func takes an int or something else only 4 bytes wide, then the argument gets casted to a pointer type which sign-extends it. Except the compiler (gcc?) should warn you even without flags like -Wall, but hey, maybe you have weird-ass macros or something which obfuscate it.

Alternatively what you mean by passing is the fact that you **return** it (as opposed to passing as an argument). That could be easily explained by C defaulting to **int** as a return value if function declaration is missing. So in that case make sure you got stuff declared.